# how to run a jar file with editplus

Tags: java, jar, editplus

I want to run a jar file in editplus3 but I dont´n know how do it. My program take text structured and converte it to XML structure but it works fine. I take a program in a jar and this jar I want run on editplus. I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just set up an external command (or a "user-defined tool" as EditPlus calls it) which runs:

```
java -jar <your-jar-file> <arguments>
```

Comment: That's great! You might want to accept the answer in that case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a Java targeted editor/IDE, like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org). Editplus, while *great* (I use it too) is simply not designed/suited for this particular task. Use the right tool for the job.